# Consuming cookies in web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I have set a cookie in an mvc application in whic I have a MVC controller and a API Controller.
Now I need to consume this cookie in both the controllers
This is how I get cookie in the MVC controller.

```
public static bool TryGetSessionCookie(HttpRequestBase request, out SessionInfo sessionInfo)
        {
            sessionInfo = null;

            try
            {
                HttpCookie authCookie = request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
                if (authCookie != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authTicket.UserData))
                    {
                        sessionInfo = authTicket.UserData;
                        if (sessionInfo != null)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Which is working fine in the normal MVC controller

```
SessionCookieHandler.TryGetSessionCookie(this.Request, out sessionInfo);
```

and getting failed in API controller
Getting error

> cannot convert from 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' to
>   'System.Web.HttpRequestBase'

So, how can I get the cookie in API contoller??

Comment: Read https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies & http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-set-cookies-in-Asp-Net-web-api/